# Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InertiaHeadProps'. error in Inertia js Head tag

Tags: reactjs, jsx, inertiajs

I'm using Inertiajs with reactjs and when I use  tag, as like as the official document of [Inertiajs](https://inertiajs.com/title-and-meta), I have error of
`Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InertiaHeadProps'.`

my code is:

```
<Head>
    <title>{title}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="description" />
    <meta name="author" content="author" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href={icon} />
</Head>
```

[image]

Comment: could you please provide more information, like whole page with head tag